# Chart.js LineChart not full parent width

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, charts, chart.js

I'm making a linechart with chart.js in react but I have a problem. my chart only takes up around 50% of its parent with on big screen (mobile works fine). I've tried setting in css the canvas width and inline css width but nothing seem to work or effect it in any way.
I added an image below:
code

```
options: {
        animation: false,
        maintainAspectRatio: true,
        responsive: true,
        scales: {
          x: {
            type: 'time',
            time: {
              unit: 'day',
            },
          },
        },
      },


<div className="dash-content-child" id="dash-graph-container">
  <canvas id="canvasRef" ref={canvasRef}></canvas>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#dash-graph-container{
          grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 3;
          width: 100%;
          height: 99%;
          animation: none;
          transition: none;
          padding: 0;
   #canvasRef{
     width: 100%;
   }
}
```

I've tried to add more data but its trying to squeeze in rather then stretch it

The height there 99% because if i put it to a 100% it make 3 times of the size for some reason feel free to give advice for that aswell :D

[image]